# Is this a valid XML syntax?

Tags: xml, loadrunner

Loadrunner documentation for the function `lr_xml_insert()` includes the following:

```
    //Insert an attribute to the root
    lr_xml_insert("Xml={ParamXml}",
        "Query=/mercury",
        "ResultParam=Result",
        "Position=attribute",
        "XmlFragment=typeAttr=\"good\"",
        LAST
    );

    lr_message(lr_eval_string ("/* Insert root attribute:\n{Result}\n"));
```

**Output:**

```
<mercury> 
     <employee>
         <name>Thomas Bertram</name>
         <cubicle>227</cubicle>
         <extension>2145</extension>
     </employee>
     <employee> 
         <name>Fanny Price</name>
         ... 
     </employee>
     typeAttr="good"
</mercury>
```

Does this follow XML syntax rules? I'm referring specifically to the attribute value being inserted as a child instead of into the opening tag of `<mercury>`. Sticking this xml into an online xml validator does not throw an error. IE doesn't throw a validation error either when displaying the

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's valid, but that isn't an attribute, it is a text node.

Comment: Thanks. It would seem the loadrunner function is not really inserting an attribute! Guess this goes to HP support.

Comment: The LoadRunner product help clearly states that this is what is going to happen. Your SO question is about the validity of the XML which was properly answered. If you would like to know how to insert an attribute to an XML please ask an additional question or use the LoadRunner support forum.

Comment: Clearly, the behavior is different from what the document states. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509383/how-to-insert-an-attribute-into-xml-root-node-in-loadrunner-using-lr-xml-insert