# How to insert an attribute into XML root node in Loadrunner using lr_xml_insert()

Tags: xml, xpath, loadrunner

I'm trying to insert an attribute into the root node of an XML fragment in loadrunner, using the lr_xml_insert function.

**Code Fragment:**

```
char *inputXML=
     "<a>" 
        "<b>" 
            "<c></c>"
        "</b>"
     "</a>";

lr_save_string(inputXML,"paramInputXML");

lr_xml_insert("Xml={paramInputXML}",
              "Query=/a",
              "ResultParam=Result",
              "Position=attribute",
              "XmlFragment=attribValue=\"0\"",
              LAST);
lr_output_message(lr_eval_string("String after insertion: {Result}"));
```

**Desired output:**

```
String after insertion: <a attribValue="0"><b><c/></b></a>
```

Actual Loadrunner output

```
String after insertion: <a><b><c/></b>attribValue="0"</a>
```

The function behaves as expected if the xpath query is /a/b or /a/b/c instead of /a

Comment: FYI, be careful of terminology like "root node." The *root node* of a fragment could be properly understood to mean the (invisible) node that is the parent of the outermost element(s). If you say "element" instead of "node", that helps make sure you are understood correctly.

Comment: @LarsH Thanks for highlighting the distinction.

Comment: @RaGe, just got the word from the dev team and this will be fixed in the next patch.

Comment: @Buzzy, Awesome, thank you for the update. Is there any way to get a patch for an older version? We're not on 12 yet.

Comment: @RaGe It is possible through your HP Support subscription. You will have to describe the issue and you can use the number 96462 for reference. This is the issue number within the development bug tracking system. But IMHO I think you should just upgrade to 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the issue within the product code (12.01) and it seems to be a product issue specific to this case. It seems that when the root element is selected it automatically changes the Position argument to 'child'. I have opened a defect in our internal systems.

Thank you very much for finding this issue.